# Deprecated warning with has_many_through statement in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following relationship

```
class User
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :friends, :through => :relationships, -> select: 'friends.*,    relationships.weight', order: 'weight DESC'
```

When I upgrade to Rails 4, I got the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Service.has_many :friends declaration are deprecated: :order,:select.
```

How should I fix this? In general, is there a working in progress reference for Rails 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 4, any of the options that you would see in a normal `User.where(...)` style query would now go in a lambda. This includes `:order` and `:select`:

```
has_many :friends, -> { select("friends.*, relationships.weight").order("weight desc") }, :through => :relationships
```

Note that the Proc does need to be the second parameter to `has_many`, so the `:through =>` part needs to stay at the end.